# How to check if a value already exists in the database in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I've a database that I will populate with items after I parse a JSON response. How can I check if the values are already present in the database and prevent inserting again ?

Eg. Name of Database: Exicom.sqlite

Name of table: TimeReport

Fields in Database: userID, clientName

I am using SQLite in android.

Thanks for your input

This is my HELPER class. I've skipped opening and closing the database as it will be too long. Followed up by where I will call the method to insert values into the database.

```
public static final String indexNo = "index_no";
public static final String user_id = "userId";
public static final String company_id = "companyId";
public static final String user_name = "username";
public static final String client_Id = "clientId";
public static final String project_Id = "projectId";
public static final String report_Id = "reportId";
public static final String niv_1  = "niv1";
public static final String niv_2 = "niv2";
public static final String work_type_id = "workTypeId";
public static final String time_type_id = "timeTypeId";
public static final String date_id = "dateId";
public static final String month_id = "monthId";
public static final String year_id = "yearId";
public static final String hourS = "hours";
public static final String private_comment = "privateComment";
public static final String Ncomment = "comment";
public static final String mod_flag = "modFlag";
public static final String new_flag = "newFlag";
public static final String open_flag = "openFlag";
public static final String delete_flag = "deleteFlag";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "CopernicusDB.sqlite";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "TimeReportTable";
private static final int    DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private final Context context;
private static DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
private static SQLiteDatabase db;
private static String TAG = "##---SecondActivityUserHelper---##";
public SecondActivityUserHelper(Context ctx)
{
this.context = ctx;
DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        Log.v(TAG,"The DatabaseHelper method ");
    }

    public long insertIntoDatabase(String companyId,String username, String dateId,
            String clientId,String projectId,String niv1,String niv2,String workTypeId,String timeTypeId,
            String hours,String comment,String privateComment,String openFlag,String reportId) 
            {
            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
            initialValues.put(company_id, companyId);
            initialValues.put(user_name, username);
            initialValues.put(date_id,dateId);
            initialValues.put(client_Id,clientId);
            initialValues.put(project_Id,projectId);
            initialValues.put(niv_1,niv1);
            initialValues.put(niv_2,niv2);
            initialValues.put(work_type_id,workTypeId);
            initialValues.put(time_type_id,timeTypeId);
            initialValues.put(hourS, hours);
            initialValues.put(Ncomment, comment);
            initialValues.put(private_comment,privateComment);
            initialValues.put(open_flag, openFlag);
            initialValues.put(report_Id,reportId);
            Log.v(TAG, "Inserted into database sucessfully");
            return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
            }
```

}

```
useradapter.openDatabase();
long id = dB.insertIntoDatabase(  newcompanyid,newusername,newdate,
newClientId,newprojectId,newniv1,newniv2,newworktypeid,newtimetypeid,
newhours,newcomment,newprivatecomment,newopen,newreportid);
                             useradapter.closeDatabase();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an object that will hold your data, eg. `ClientData`
Create a method for fetching all data from the database

```
public List<ClientData> selectAll() {
   List<ClientData> list = new ArrayList<ClientData>();
   Cursor cursor = this.myDataBase.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "userID, clientName" },
   null, null, null, null, null);
   if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
           list.add(new ClientData(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1)));
         } while (cursor.moveToNext());
   }
   if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
         cursor.close();
   }
   return list;
}
```

Before executing your insert statements, fetch all data and then check if data exists:

```
if (!list.contains(clientData)) {
    executeInsert();
}
```

I am not sure if SQLite supports stored procedures, but if it does, you could write a stored procedure for that as well.

Answer (score 1):

1 )if your looking for the unique id than make your id field as auto increment and insert only name value

2 ) if you are not looking for unique than retrieve the all data for this table store in the array than compare your inserted value with existing value in data base

Answer (score 1):

In your example table:

When you create your table you can set your name as unique (if that is what you want unique) with the following (Using a `SQLiteOpenHelper`).

```
String createPlayerTable = "create table " +
                TIME_REPORT +
                " (" +
                USER_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement not null," +
                CLIENT_NAME + " text not null," +                    
                "UNIQUE("+CLIENT_NAME+")"+
                ");";
```

Then in you insert `insertIntoDatabase` method use

```
db.insertOrThrow(TIME_REPORT, null, initialValues);
```

instead of

```
db.insert(TIME_REPORT, null, initialValues);
```

This may throw a `SQLiteConstraintException` so you will have add a try/catch.

Hope this is what you need.