# Android SDK - Database Connection

Tags: java, android, database

How would I go about making it so when you click on a button it would take the value of EditText1 and EditText 2 than check a database to see if they match and if they do it should saying success.

This is just for testing, I just want to learn how to do this.

This is my code so far, I'm just not sure how to do the whole database part.

```
    final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            EditText text2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: so your question is how to get the text from edittext or how to check if the data is present in database

Comment: Check if the data is present in the database.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820905/how-to-check-if-a-value-already-exists-in-the-database-in-android. check this if it helps

Comment: I read through that but I'm still a bit confused on how to do this.

Comment: what is the confusion and what does your database contain

Comment: It is a users database so you can login. How do I make it connect to the database? And how do I make it check? That link just confused me more D:

Comment: first is it a remote db on a server or a local database.

Comment: Remote database, sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

{

str1 = editText1.getText.toString();

str2 = editText2.getText.toString();

}

{

cursor c = db.query(select all ids);

while(c.moveToNext){

if(c.getId() == str1 && c.getId() == str2)

{

do sumthing

}

}

}

Comment: I'm getting errors on this line.

cursor c = db.query(select all ids);

Comment: Can't find cursor, db.query or select all

Comment: i just wrote logic of your idea.

Comment: you need to create sqlitedatabase object with some ids. & then through cursor object you fetch them & match with your edittext fields.

Comment: Can you link me to how I would setup sqlitedatabase and stuff? Or update your answer with it, please? :)